# Extending limits from sequences to functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

For some sequences, I can show that it converges to some value (e.g. $e$ defined by $(1+1/n)^n$ over integers as n approaches infinity) but for a function that is defined the same way as the sequence over the real numbers (e.g. $f(x)=(1+1/x)^x)$), how do I show it converges to the same value?

Comment: You use something about the function, such as [monotonicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function). $\:$ (Consider $\sin(\pi \hspace{-0.03 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.04 in}x)$.) $\hspace{1.48 in}$

Comment: I tried to do monotonicity on e but I showed that with binomial theorem, not over real numbers

Comment: differentiate the function $\;$

Comment: Also, note that the $\hspace{.04 in}f$ you gave does not actually depend on its input. $\:$ You should fix that before doing my previous comment. $\;\;\;\;$